# Async/await gera uma nova thread?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Ao ler sobre métodos async/await, é dito que que usar estas palavras-chave por si só não fará com que o seu método rode em uma nova thread. Porém, obtenho a saída abaixo ao rodar o meu código. Um thread foi gerada para executar o código que vem logo abaixo do await. Gostaria de entender por que isso ocorre.

> 19:23:38.277 Thread #692 Program Start   19:23:38.293 Thread #692
> Experiment code is synchronous before await   19:23:38.293 Thread #692
> Experiment code is asynchronous after first await   19:23:38.293
> Thread #13  Task que eu criei (rodando em thread do pool)
> 19:23:38.293 Thread #512 Não pedi para essa linha ser executada em uma
> thread diferente.   19:23:38.293 Thread #692 Execução do metodo
> principal   19:23:38.293 Thread #13  Não pedi para essa linha ser
> executada em uma thread diferente (2).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Run();
    }

    private void Print(string txt)
    {
        string dateStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Thread #{1}\t{2}", dateStr, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, txt);
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Print("Program Start");
        Experiment();
        Print("Execução do metodo principal");  
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private async Task Experiment()
    {
        Print("Experiment code is synchronous before await");
        await SomethingElse();
        Print(" Não pedi para essa linha ser executada em thread diferente (2).");
    }

    private async Task SomethingElse()
    {
        Print("Experiment code is asynchronous after first await");
        string dateStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
        await Task.Run(() =>  Print("Task que eu criei (rodando em thread do pool)"));
        Print(" Não pedi para essa linha ser executada em uma thread diferente.");
            }
}
```

Comment: Estranho, eu não saberia explicar, eu executei e não aconteceu isso.

Comment: Executei no LINQPad 6 agora aqui e o resultado mudou um pouco, mas a dúvida continua, embora eu já tenha ideia do que ocorra. Quando eu executo o método Task.Run, ele pega um thread do pool para executar o código passado. Nesse momento a thread principal retorna execução do meu método  Run. No meu método assíncrono, ainda há trechos de código a serem executados após o await. Aparentemente uma thread do pool é novamente solicitada para executá-los.

Comment: Sim, mas não acho que deveria acontecer (mesmo que aconteça) e acho estranho que aconteça só em alguns casos.

Comment: Antes dessa experiência, se eu tivesse que "chutar" uma opinião, iria dizer que a thread principal cederia tempo para executar o que restou após o await nos métodos assíncronos, mas agora vejo que não é bem assim.

Comment: Tasks rodam em threads na threadpool. async/await gera uma Task.

Answer (score 1):

**A resposta curta é:** O uso do await gera uma máquina de estados que contém AwaitUnsafeOnComplete, este método não mantém o contexto de execução.

EDIT: Vale ressaltar que o uso do AwaitUnsafeOnComplete é estratégico, pois dificilmente ocorreria em um cenário real. Neste seu experimento ocorreu, pois a execução é quase instantânea. Experimente usar desse modo:

```
await Task.Run(() => PrintLongo("Task que eu criei (rodando em thread do pool)"));


private void PrintLongo(string txt)
{
    Task.Delay(200);
    string dateStr = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff");
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Thread #{1}\t{2}", dateStr, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, txt);
}
```

Para entender melhor, temos que analisar o código gerado.

Dado o código abaixo:

```
await Task.Run(() =>  Print("Task que eu criei (rodando em thread do pool)"));
```

Podemos ver a máquina de estados que foi gerada a partir do seu exemplo:

[image: Máquina de estados gerada pelo uso do await]

E em IL:

[image: Código em Intermediate Language]

Observando as linhas:

```
IL_003e: call instance bool [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter::get_IsCompleted()
IL_0043: brtrue.s IL_0085
```

Vemos que ao executar get_IsCompleted e se for verdadeiro ele avança para:

```
    IL_0085: ldloca.s 1
    IL_0087: call instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter::GetResult()
    IL_008c: nop
    IL_008d: ldarg.0
    IL_008e: ldfld class Program Program/'<SomethingElse>d__4'::'<>4__this'
    IL_0093: ldstr " Não pedi para essa linha ser executada em uma thread diferente."
    IL_0098: call instance void Program::Print(string)
    IL_009d: nop
    IL_009e: leave.s IL_00b8
```

O foco aqui é notar o contexto de execução, que mantém as informações das threads em um fluxo lógico de controle. Temos métodos que já fazem isso automaticamente, como o Task.Run. O método captura do encadeamento de chamada e o armazena com a instância. Quando o associado com a tarefa executa um determinado delegado, ele o executa usando o contexto armazenado.
Porém, nem todos os métodos no BCL irão capturar e restaurar automaticamente o contexto de execução. Como podemos ver, de acordo com o uso no seu experimento, o código gerado nos fornece um **AsyncMethodBuilder.AwaitUnsafeOnComplete**, Esse método é marcado como "unsafe".

Seguindo o seu experimento, altero para:

```
Task.Run(() => Print("Task que eu criei (rodando em thread do pool)")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

E então, com o uso do GetResult() não mais utilizamos o AwaitUnsafeOnComplete e o contexto é mantido.

```
IL_0007: nop
IL_0008: ldarg.0
IL_0009: ldfld class Program Program/'<SomethingElse>d__4'::'<>4__this'
IL_000e: ldstr "Experiment code is asynchronous after first await"
IL_0013: call instance void Program::Print(string)
IL_0018: nop
IL_0019: ldarg.0
IL_001a: ldfld class Program Program/'<SomethingElse>d__4'::'<>4__this'
IL_001f: ldftn instance void Program::'<SomethingElse>b__4_0'()
IL_0025: newobj instance void [System.Runtime]System.Action::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_002a: call class [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::Run(class [System.Runtime]System.Action)
IL_002f: callvirt instance valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter [System.Runtime]System.Threading.Tasks.Task::GetAwaiter()
IL_0034: stloc.1
IL_0035: ldloca.s 1
IL_0037: call instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter::GetResult()
IL_003c: nop
IL_003d: ldarg.0
IL_003e: ldfld class Program Program/'<SomethingElse>d__4'::'<>4__this'
IL_0043: ldstr " Não pedi para essa linha ser executada em uma thread diferente."
IL_0048: call instance void Program::Print(string)
IL_004d: nop
IL_004e: leave.s IL_0068
```

Executando com o GetResult(), temos o output:

```
01:37:18.169 Thread #1  Program Start
01:37:18.232 Thread #1  Experiment code is synchronous before await
01:37:18.233 Thread #1  Experiment code is asynchronous after first await
01:37:18.300 Thread #4  Task que eu criei (rodando em thread do pool)
01:37:18.302 Thread #1   Não pedi para essa linha ser executada em uma thread diferente.
01:37:18.302 Thread #1   Não pedi para essa linha ser executada em thread diferente (2).
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]